# AWS CodeDeploy cannot connect to a Github repo with "invalid characters"

Tags: amazon-web-services, github

I am trying to give AWS CodeDeploy access to a Github repo, in order to manually trigger the first deployment.

The Git repo has periods in its name (see example below), which raises an error: "Token name contains invalid characters"

Image of AWS error:
[image: Image of AWS error]

Is there a work-around to this? or must I rename my Git repo?

Comment: It looks like it is asking for just your username

Comment: Thanks, @osowskit! It looks like you do, indeed, have the option to enter *just* the user name. Then, AWS reveals an additional input box, which can interpret the periods (i.e., those "invalid characters"). (Previously, for "Github account", I've entered the full username/<repo-name> combo, so AWS may have released some new frontend changes...)

Answer (score 0):

As noted above it looks like it is looking for a username. I believe you might need to allow AWS to have the correct permission in order to have it push your AWS code to github. I would check the permission to make sure the github settings are allowing AWS in personal web token or authorized Oauth apps.